# assign a column using a value from another column to modify a string from a third one. [pandas dataframe]

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda, assign

`df_certain.assign(flagged_context=df_certain.context.str[:(df_certain.answers_index)])`

returns me a column with NaNs.

these are the column datatypes:

answers_index int64
context Object

I want a column with the string in context until given index.

I've tried using lambda and such but it won't work.

Comment: I think you should give a _minimal reproducible example_ and a clear expected output.

Comment: sure.

`df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'answers_index':[2,4,5],'context':['abcdef','abcdef','abcdef']})`

I want to obtain a third column 'flagged_context':

ab
abcd
abcde
@abokey

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*list comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with slicing :

```
df["flagged_context"] = [t[:s] for s, t in zip(df["answers_index"], df["context"])]
​
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

   answers_index context flagged_context
0              2  abcdef              ab
1              4  abcdef            abcd
2              5  abcdef           abcde
```